# Azure DevOps Shared Query permission not inheriting from Project Administrator Group

Tags: azure-devops

I am in the project administrator group, since we have a requirement to set the shared query to read-only to Contributors, I toggled the permission for Contributors to Deny except for "Read"

When I try to create new shared query, it says:

TF401256: You do not have Write permission for query Shared Queries.

I clicked on the three dots and bring up the "Permission for Shared Queries" menu, searched my name and a few other people in the Project Administrator Group or Project Collection Administrator Group, it shows all "Deny" permission except for the "Read" for all of us.

When I hover over, it says our permission is being inherited through the {project}\Contributors, but we are in the Administrator group.

Why is that and How can I fix it? I cannot even overwrite the permission. It is stuck at being inherited from the Contributor group.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep0Lj.jpg)

Comment: I found a solution. We should not use "Deny" but "Not Set" in order to let it inherit from Administrator group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are in a different group(project administrator group and Contributors), check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page#permission-states):

In the Azure DevOps, for most groups and almost all permissions, **Deny** overrides **Allow**. If a user belongs to two groups, and one of them has a specific permission set to **Deny**, that user is not able to perform tasks that require that permission even if they belong to a group that has that permission set to **Allow**.

This is why you get the error message. You could open project settings->Permissions->Search the permission group `{project}\Contributors`->click the tab Members and remove your account. Then you could create new shared query

**Update1**

Steps:

Open project settings->Teams->select the team->click the tab Settings->add Administrator, then we could move our account.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I checked my Contributor group, so it doesn't directly contain me, it contains a team, and then I am in the team. I am the team administrator, so I tried but cannot remove myself as I am the team admin.

Comment: By the way, when I manually override the permission, I see the green check mark. However it doesn't actually work. It will revert back to inheriting from the Contributors group. I am reporting the issue to Microsoft community.

Comment: Hi @minilude, This is by design instead of a bug, if you want to remove yourself, you need to add another user as a team admin, then you could leave the team, check the update1.

Comment: Hi @minilude, By the way, If this answer is helpful, would you please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Hi Vito, thanks for the replying. I just think I shouldn't remove myself from the team admin position. Why would I do that? I am the team admin and I am supposed to be in that team as an admin, not another person. I tried to manually override the permission (for shared queries) just for myself, but it didn't work. I see the green check mark but it will revert back to say the permission is inherited from Contributor - which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

link to MS forum for this issue (or similar posted by other people):

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Project-administrator-cannot-save-shared/1339863

It just doesn't sound right to me that in order to have admin permission you cannot be in any team. That maybe workable for a test account but for an organization this workaround or restriction could mess things up a lot.